# Getting a list of all intents from a package

Tags: android, android-intent

For a project I want to launch a specific application that will be installed on the android tablet. 
It's not an application we have any control over (it's entirely third party) and I require a workflow for it similar to the way the Image_Capture Camera Intent works (ie, launch it, wait for it to finish and recieve the data in the onActivityResult function)
While I can launch the application using the following code:

```
    Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.thirdparty.package");
    if(intent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent,MY_INT_FLAG);
    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("This device does not appear to have the application installed").setPositiveButton("Okay",null).create().show();           
    }
```

it passes a resultCode of **0 (RESULT_CANCELLED)** to the onActivityResult *straight away* since it's just launching the application.

What'd I'd like is to be able to discover a list of intents for a given package. There is a function in PackageManager called **getInstalledApplications** (which is how I got the package name in the first place) however, the flag **PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS** doesn't seem to populate the metaData property of any of the resulting **ApplicationInfo** objects.

Does anyone have any insight into either getting the intent list, or mining the data out of the APK?

Comment: I fail to see how being able to "discover a list of intents for a given package" will allow you to magically rewrite the third-party application to support `startActivityForResult()`. That being said, I do not think that there is a way to get what you see from `PackageManager`.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This has nothing to do with [tag:data-mining] (tag removed). Thank you.